What are the effects of intramolecular on intermolecular forces?
I'm wondering if intramolecular forces have an effect on intermolecular ones (the converse is also interesting, but I believe that would lead to too edgy physics, which I'm not looking for here). My main instinct tells me that the former doesn't affect the latter. Science intuitions, on the other hand, suggest there might be extreme cases in which intermolecular forces can change the total molecule composition, and start affecting the whole bulk of molecules. I'm not informed enough to give a more accurate analysis, But this is a question I have had for a while now.

While I certainly have no idea what you mean by "edgy" physics, I will attempt to allay some of your qualms. First of all, we need to clarify what would constitute an effect from intramolecular and intermolecular forces. For an intramolecular force to be an intramolecular force, it has to have something to do with defining the composition of a molecule in isolation. Namely, it is an interaction that binds together distinct atoms in a particular geometry. This gives rise to the strength of bonds within a molecule, the relative angles between bonds, the electron density localized on particular atoms, etc. An intermolecular force is any interaction that causes identifiably distinct molecules to alter their relative arrangement with respect to one another: for instance, hydrogen bonding orders water molecules in a very flexible extended network.
The answer to whether the interactions that give rise to the structure of isolated molecules would have any effect on how these molecules may interact with one another is resoundingly in the affirmative. For instance, the localization of electron charge more strongly on the oxygen atom in water causes the relatively electron poor hydrogens of other water molecules to orient themselves selectively towards the oxygens of other water molecules. In fact, the "hybridization" of the electron orbitals on water causes there to be two somewhat tetrahedrally arranged regions of the oxygen atom towards which the hydrogens are oriented. This still counts as an intermolecular interaction because the relative flexibility of the network of waters shows that there are still relatively distinct identifiable molecules. The tetrahedral arrangement of the hydrogen bond network of water is shown below. 
